# Pygame does not show anything

Tags: python, pygame

i'am trying to make a game but pygame does not show my player. I think it is a coding mistake please review.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Running = True

Current_Color=pygame.Color("LIGHTBLUE")

Mouse_x,Mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

Player_image = pygame.image.load("550x804.jpg")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1300, 720])

screen.fill(pygame.Color("LIGHTBLUE"))

while Running == True:
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("LIGHTBLUE"))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
    screen.blit(Player_image ,(100,100))
    Player_image = pygame.transform.scale(Player_image, (10,20))
```

Comment: you need to call pygame.display.update() inside your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have just to add `pygame.display.update()` in the while loop:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
Running = True

Current_Color=pygame.Color("LIGHTBLUE")

Mouse_x,Mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()    
Player_image = pygame.image.load("550x804.jpg")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1300, 720])
screen.fill(pygame.Color("LIGHTBLUE"))

while Running == True:
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("LIGHTBLUE"))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
    screen.blit(Player_image ,(100,100))
    Player_image = pygame.transform.scale(Player_image, (10,20))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: that does it thanks for the help

Comment: @JorenPeers if this answered your question you should mark the it as accepted.